# Slideshow on Homepage does not fit screen until browser resize (firefox only)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, themes, slideshow

This is a wordpress issue, but I'm simply trying to fix the CSS and I'm not sure where to go.  I'm using duotive-5 as my theme, I don't think this started happening til today, so I think it's something I changed, or it happened from updating to wordpress 3.6.

If you view our site on firefox, half of the slideshow is cut off until the browser is resized. You can see this at http://www.dominicandestination.com, and you can see it happen in the latest version of Firefox.

I'm not sure why the browser renders the slideshow weird until the browser is resized.  It's hard to examine the CSS because it doesn't do it with chrome, and with firefox, after starting the inspector, the browser resizes a bit and the slideshow is displayed normally. Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: How is the height of the background image being determined? CSS or JavaScript? It looks to me like you have a bummed media query or javascript call that is determining the height of the viewport.

Comment: Okay, it would seem that one of the elements your images sits inside of is coming out to the wrong height and your images are using "inherit". This is why I hate that value, because it becomes a nightmare to find where it's coming from.

Comment: @Trendy which element is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `height:100%` to your `.dt-fullwidth-wrapper`

Add `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` to your `.dt-fullwidth-wrapper .images-li.center a:link imgr`

Comment: thanks man, added those properties with !important and it worked!